# is it okay to clearly write IP address in Nginx conf file?

Tags: nginx, server, reverse-proxy

I'm asking this because some relatives said it could represent a security flaw.

I mean, it is easy to replace the server IP with $host or the server name in the conf file but it can really be troublesome to not use it. Especially since with a variable, the proxy_pass line can change its behavior.

Like, replace:

```
proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:$port;
```

with:

```
proxy_pass http://www.example.com:$port;

proxy_pass http://$host:$port;
```

can quickly become hard with Resolver and some other stuff.

Before I was sure it was ok to write the ip address in clear in this file but now I am not so sure. The IP also appears in the hosts.

Is that safe?
Sorry if the question might sound stupid

Answer (score 0):

Using a specific IP address does assume that the IP address is static and not dynamically issued. Apart from that, if you use the host name, it still resolves to an IP address. If a bad actor has access to your config files, they would most likely be able to sniff packets on the machine using something like Fiddler to determine the IP address anyway. If your endpoints are secure this should be fine. Abstraction is really just a deterrent and not a security measure.